# Set css Color From Database in Asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to set background color dynamically? 
I set a color in Database. Then read color from database in css.

Actually I am making a webapp which have blue color button , blue color menu and extra. I have set css color from style sheet and load it in header. Now I cant pass data from my cshtml file to css file. So How is it possible to set color. Please give me a way so that I can go that way and fulfill my goal.

Comment: Are you using c# or vb.net? It's possible with either just changing the back-color in the class.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you show some stub code, we can provide specific guidance.

Comment: Actually I am making a webapp which have blue color button , blue color menu and extra. I have set css color from style sheet and load it in header. Now 
I cant pass data from my cshtml file to css file. So How is it possible to set color. Please give me a way so that I can go that way and fulfill my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an action filter to get your colors from the db ,pass those values to the layout where you use that to override some of your css style definitions.

```cs
public class MyColors : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
  {
    var primarColor = "red";
    var vb=filterContext.Controller.ViewBag;
    vb.PrimaryColor = primarColor;
    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
  }
}
```

and register this filter globally so this is applicable to the entire app.

```cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
  GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

  GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MyColors());

  FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}`
```

And in your layout.

```
<head>
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <style>
      @ { 
        var primary = String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.PrimaryColor) ? "black": ViewBag.PrimaryColor; 
       }
       h1 {
         color: @primary;
       }
     </style>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score -1):

define two styles in your .css file:

```
.blue-button{
background: #00f;
}

.red-button{
background: #f00;
}
```

Get the property from your database and save it in viewbag (or model itself, it doesn't matter).
In your view, you define your button like this:

```
 <input type="submit" class="@(ViewBag.IsThisBlue ? "blue-button" : "red-button")" value="Click Me">
```

Edit: I just realized that you actually save the color in db. Since you can't pass that to the css directly, you can use style attribute on input itself in the same way I used class attribute above.